# std::get< > fails when using a type argument instead of an index

Tags: c++, clang, tuples

I have defined a vector of tuples:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3>> myVec;
```

If I access members of the tuples by index, everything works:

```
Type1 &myVar = std::get<0>(myVec.front());
```

If I use the typename, I get an error compiling:

```
Type1 &myVar = std::get<Type1>(myVec.front());
```

Error message:

```
invalid explicitly specified argument for template parameter
```

I'm using clang on Mac OS X (the version included in XCode 6.2)

Comment: Have you enabled C++14 support in clang?

Comment: I think the overload with a type given as template does not exists. What would you do if you have a tuple<Type1, Type1> and someone invokes get<Type1>(my_tuple)? You can use boost::variant to access elements by their type as you tried in your example. But it has a completly different semantic, such that variant<Type1, Type2, Type3> means you have either exactly one element of Type1, or Type2 or Type3. Maybe not your use-case!

Comment: If you are using c++14 then simply ignore my comment above! ^^

Comment: According to [this `std::get` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get), the overloads using types are only from C++14, which you might have to enable explicitly.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that on cppreference.com